# Show k nearest neighbors for text classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn, text-classification

I have a CSV file (corpus.csv) with graded abstracts (text) in the following format in corpus:

```
Institute,    Score,    Abstract


----------------------------------------------------------------------


UoM,    3.0,    Hello, this is abstract one

UoM,    3.2,    Hello, this is abstract two and yet counting.

UoE,    3.1,    Hello, yet another abstract but this is a unique one.

UoE,    2.2,    Hello, please no more abstract.
```

I am trying to create a KNN classification program in python, which is able to get an user input abstract such as, "This is a new unique abstract" and then classify this user input abstract closest to the corpus (CSV) and also returns the score/grade of the predicted abstract. I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader,writer
import operator as op
import string
from sklearn import neighbors

#Read data from corpus
r = reader(open('corpus.csv','r'))
abstract_list = []
score_list = []
institute_list = []
row_count = 0
for row in list(r)[1:]:
    institute,score,abstract = row[0], row[1], row[2]
    if len(abstract.split()) > 0:
      institute_list.append(institute)
      score = float(score)
      score_list.append(score)
      abstract = abstract.translate(string.punctuation).lower()
      abstract_list.append(abstract)
      row_count = row_count + 1

print("Total processed data: ", row_count)

#Vectorize (TF-IDF, ngrams 1-4, no stop words) using sklearn -->
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,4),
                     min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(abstract_list)
classes = score_list
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)
clf.fit(response, classes)
predicted = clf.predict(response)
```

At the moment if I use the aforementioned code then the "**predicted**" gives an output, which is for example [3.2]. However, I also want the output to be [3.2, UoM, "Hello, this is abstract two and yet counting."]

I want to show the k nearest neighbors (not just the score but also the corresponding institution name and abstract). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

After fitting the model, you'll need to [run the model against a point](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.kneighbors):

```
>>> samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
>>> neigh.fit(samples)
NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
>>> print(neigh.kneighbors([[1., 1., 1.]]))
(array([[0.5]]), array([[2]]))
```

This returns two arrays, where the first is a list of distances, and the second is a list of the indices of the nearest neighbors. In order to print in your desired format, you will need to perform a lookup of the abstracts given the indices of the second list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please let me know how I can use .kneighbors() for my use case?